# Foreign key with a name of an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, model-associations

I have the following migration:

```rb
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table "customers" do |t|
      t.string "name"
    end

    create_table "items" do |t|
      t.integer "customer"
    end
  end
end
```

and models:

```rb
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, foreign_key: :customer
end
```

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: :customer
end
```

The following code loops infinitely because the column used in `foreign key` has the same name as an existing model:

```
2.5.1 :001 > Customer.create(name: "John")
=> #<Customer id: 1, name: "John">

2.5.1 :002 > Customer.first
=> #<Customer id: 1, name: "John"> 

2.5.1 :003 > Customer.first.items
Traceback (most recent call last):
SystemStackError (stack level too deep)
```

How do I reference the column which name clashes with an existing name?

Comment: You have a few issues there which lets me presume that you did not go through [the associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - `customer` should be `customer_id` - then there's no need for `foreign_key`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate solution seems to be renaming foreign key column `customer` to `customer_id`, but if you REALLY need the column to be named `customer`, just change association's name, because that's where Rails gets confused. For example:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_customer, foreign_key: :customer, class_name: 'Customer'
end
```

Note, that when the class name can't be inferred from the association name, you have to specify it using `class_name: 'Customer'`

Comment: That worked. I will wait some time before I accept it as an anwser because I wonder if there is a solution that doesn't involve renaming the association's name. Meanwhile, could you elaborate on why exactly my code was looping?

Comment: Actually, it seems that you can achieve the same with `Item.where('customer = ?', Customer.first.id)`. Still, renaming the association seems to be better because `Item.where(customer: Customer.first.id)` and `Customer.first.items` still raises `SystemStackError`, which is quite strange. I'm not sure why it's the case, but I'm fairly sure that naming foreign key column exactly the same as a model and an association is not a good idea. Maybe someone else could explain more?

Comment: You have an infinite loop because you have an attribute customer on Item which creates an `customer` class method AND you define an association `belongs_to :customer` which also creates a `customer` method ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to)). As @ahawrylak answered, change the name of the association (and specify the class name), or change the attribute `customer` in db to `customer_id` or whatever key name you want.